# Android ViewPager inside a NestedScrollView

Tags: android, xml, android-viewpager, android-nestedscrollview

I need to show some text and at the bottom I need two tabs. The current code works only if the text is small, if the text fills the whole screen, then the tabs are not shown when scrolling.
[image]
[image]
My activity XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context="dk.zispa.vibetasks.TaskDetailedView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/task_view_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/taskTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/taskBreadcrumbs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/taskTitle"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/secondaryText"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/taskBreadcrumbs"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@color/divider" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/taskDescription"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/divider"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/secondaryText" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/hoursInfo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/taskDescription"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/taskEstimatedHours"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/orange"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/taskWorkedHours"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/hoursInfo">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/book_tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabGravity="fill">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/book_description_tab_item"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TAB1" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/book_reviews_tab_item"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TAB2" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Do you have any ideas how can I make the tabs visible when you scroll down?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace the LinearLayout with RelativeLayout. Put the task_view_layout with alignParentTop="true" and the view pager with alignParentBottom="true" and layoutBelow="@+id/task_view_layout"

Comment: That didn't help, still cannot see the tabs if you have to scroll.